# Batch Count Files And Subfolders in a directory

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have 100 folders with subfolders inside them
i want to count how many subfolders i have in each folder and how many files.
then i want all to be in a txt file with the name of the folder the number of subfolder in each one and number of files in each one.
i would also like to have a title on the top of each column .
so it will look like this:
[image]
Now im using this code which almost work

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
   PUSHD "%%G"
   FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a-d /b * ^|find /C /V ""')  DO echo %%G %%H>>"..\count.txt" Files
   FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a:d /b * ^|find /C /V ""')  DO echo %%G %%I>>"..\count.txt" Folders
 POPD )
```

it gives me the correct sub folders 
and also the correct files in a folder.
i dont know how ro make the titles on top and also how to get the files count and folder count next to each other.
in my code they are one under the other

Add on to the question , you guys found the solution for the first part , now id like to add info on another sub folder but i dont want 2 scripts to do that , i want all display in the txt file. so it will look something like this:[image: Second Part]

Comment: you have been provided with four answers, and have confirmed that at least two of them work. It would certainly help this site and potential future responders and viewers if you were choose your preferred solution and mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: You are right i just waited for magoo to see my comment about output this to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aligning columns requires substrings and as this is in a (code block) it requires delayed expansion.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(Echo Folders            #Sub  #Files   ##Sub ##Files
 FOR /D %%G in (*) DO (
   PUSHD "%%G"
   Set /A "Sub#=Files#=0,SUB##=Files##=0" 
   Set "Folders=%%~G                  "
   FOR /F %%H in ('dir /a-d /b 2^>NUL^|find /C /V "" ') DO Set Files#=%%H
   FOR /F %%I in ('dir /ad  /b 2^>NUL^|find /C /V "" ') DO Set Sub#=%%I
   if !Sub#! gtr 0 (
      FOR /F %%H in ('dir /a-d /b /S 2^>NUL^|find /C /V "" ') DO Set Files##=%%H
      FOR /F %%I in ('dir /ad  /b /S 2^>NUL^|find /C /V "" ') DO Set Sub##=%%I
      Set /A "Files##-=Files#,Sub##-=Sub#"
   )
   Set    "Sub#=       !Sub#!"
   Set  "Files#=       !Files#!"
   Set   "Sub##=       !Sub##!"
   Set "Files##=       !Files##!"
   Echo !Folders:~,15! !Sub#:~-7! !Files#:~-7! !Sub##:~-7! !Files##:~-7!
   POPD 
)) > "count.txt"
start count.txt
```

Sample output

```
Folders            #Sub  #Files   ##Sub ##Files
ManagedWinApi         0       5       0       0
vb                    0      16       0       0
PoSh                  9     249       2     181
_StackOverflow        1       0       0       5
```

Comment: Is it possible go even dipper in the folders? i mean if i have a folder a subfolder and a subfolder inside , can i count these folders and files also? what i need to add to the code? thanx

Comment: For a total count, simply add the `/s` switch to the two dir commands. When counting each level seperately, how to display the results? But this would be a new question.

Comment: Im not looking for a total count im asking if its possible to add another line so it display how many folder and files are inside the second sub folder in the hierarchy.

Comment: If you don't want to differentiate between the subsub folders or display the subsub folder names you can count the total and subtract the above  results.

Comment: Yes i know i can subtract that and see the results i thought of a cool way to see it in the text file, i guess there is a command to show whats 2 levels deep in the folder hierarchy. so ill have `Folders #sub #Files  ##sub ##Files` its not that important but its cool to have that option also :)

Comment: See above revised Version, earning a +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sp12=            "
SET "outfilename=u:\outfile.txt"
DEL "%outfilename%" >NUL 2>nul
CALL :form "   Folders" 11 "#sub" 9 #Files 8
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
 PUSHD "%%G"
 FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a:d /b * 2^>nul^|find /C /V ""') DO (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a-d /b * 2^>nul^|find /C /V ""') DO (
   CALL :form :: 12 "%%H" 6 "%%I" 9
  )
 )
 POPD 
)
GOTO :EOF
:form
FOR %%z IN ("%cd%") DO SET "$1=%%~nxz%sp12%"
IF "%~1" neq "::" SET "$1=%~1%sp12%"
SET "$2=%sp12%%~3"
IF "%~5"=="0" (SET "$3=") ELSE SET "$3=%sp12%%~5"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF DEFINED $3 (
 ECHO(!$1:~0,%2!!$2:~-%4!!$3:~-%6!>>"%outfilename%"
) ELSE (
 ECHO(!$1:~0,%2!!$2:~-%4!>>"%outfilename%"
)
endlocal
GOTO :eof
```

Redirection to your file is simply *thisbatch*>yourfilename

Dealing with the main body first, the only change is to ensure the innermost `for` is in the context of the middle `for` so that all of the `%%x` are in-scope when the formatting procedure `:form` is `call`ed.

The `:form` procedure sets `$1` to the name and extension of the current directory and appends 12 spaces. The two count fields need to be right-justified, so append their values to 12 spaces in `$2`, `$3`

For the special circumstance where the third column is a suppressed-zero, clear `$3` and then, within a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion/endlocal` bracket to overcome poison-character problems, use `$3` as a switch to generate 1 or 2 columns. Each column is either the first n or last n characters, `n` having been input as a parameter.

The special value `::` in parameter 1 signals the required display in column1 is the directoryname. If the parameter supplied is not `::` then the parameter, suitably padded and with the quotes removed is used. This permits the header to be generated.

Interesting exercise.

---

Amendment - include setting of `outfilename` to convenient place on my system and apply appropriate redirectors.

Comment: Thanx for the reply magoo your answer worked the best but doesnt create a txt file how can i add the txt file?

Comment: Redirection to your file is simply *thisbatch*>yourfilename. OR you can put `>>yourfilename` at the end of each `echo` OR you could put a new line containing just `(` before the `FOR /D %%G...` line and its matching `)>yourfilename` before the `first `goto :eof`

Comment: The >>filename after echo didnt worked, i get empty file `ECHO(!$1:~0,%2!!$2:~-%4!!$3:~-%6! 
) >>count.txt ELSE (
 ECHO(!$1:~0,%2!!$2:~-%4! 
) >>count.txt`

Comment: Hey i get an error "The system cannot find the path" when using `SET "outfilename=u:\outfile.txt"` but when im using for instance D: \outfile.txt it saves the file to D , how can i save it from the root folder im running the script from?

Comment: `%~dp0filename.txt` should achieve that - or `.\filename.txt` - try `echo`ing each of these and observe which one takes your fancy.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` command provides the information you need in the returned summary lines at the bottom:

> ```cmd
> >>> dir "D:\Data"
>  Volume in drive D has no label.
>  Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000
>
> Directory of D:\Data
>
> 2017/03/13  02:00    <DIR>          .
> 2017/03/13  02:00    <DIR>          ..
>
>                0 File(s)              0 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)   1'073'741'824 bytes free
> ```

This can be used to achieve your goal:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

> "count.txt" (
    echo Folders    #Sub    #Files
    echo/
    for /D %%G in ("*") do (
        set "CURRDIR=%%~G" & set /A "NUMDIRS=0, NUMFILE=0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F %%H in ('dir /A /W "!CURRDIR!" 2^> nul') do (
            set /A "NUMFILE=NUMDIRS+2, NUMDIRS=%%H-2"
        )
        echo(!CURRDIR!    !NUMDIRS!    !NUMFILE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: This code gives wrong results on some of the folders, for instance in a folder that has 2 folders inside it counts 3

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I did not take into account that `dir` also counts the `.` and `..` directories, but now it should be fine... Note that `dir /A` also returns hidden items; if you do not want that, remove `/A`...

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add an alternative method using `RoboCopy`, which I believe may be pretty quick:

```bat
@(Echo("FolderNames","#Subs","#Files"
For /D %%A In (*) Do @If Not "%%A"=="" (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Skip=5 Tokens=3" %%B In (
        'RoboCopy /E /L /NFL /NDL /NJH "%%A" Null *.*') Do @If Not Defined _s (
        Set/A "_s=%%B-1") Else (If Not Defined _f Set "_f=%%B")
    Echo("%%A","!_s!","!_f!"
    EndLocal))>Counts.csv
```

*…this is however untested.*